# Refactoring code to make it more reusable

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I am using the mail gem, and in order to deliver an e-mail you need to do something like this:

```
Mail.deliver do
 from Config.mail['user_name']
 to Config.mail['recipients']
 subject  "Process has completed"
 body "Process has completed an import at #{Time.now}."
end
```

I have created many different methods that contain that block in order to send out different e-mail types. After looking it over again though it seems that for each e-mail type the only parts that change are the subject and body. The from and to to stay the same. In other words, I seem to be repeating myself quite often.

I was hoping I could have a method like this:

```
def send_notification(notification)
 Mail.deliver do
  from Config.mail['user_name']
  to Config.mail['recipients']
  <some way I pass in the subject and body here from another method>
 end
end
```

And I would have a series of other methods for types of notifications that would only have to contain the subject and body information:

```
def job_start_notification
  subject "Started"
  body "Stuff Started"
end
```

I was thinking of passing in the `job_start_notification` method as a lambda into the `send_notification` method but that won't work because subject and body are methods, and for some reason they aren't being called in the context of the `Mail.deliver` block.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be this:

```
def send_notification(subject, body)
  Mail.deliver do
    from Config.mail['user_name']
    to Config.mail['recipients']
    subject subject
    body body
  end
end
send_notification "foo", "your foo is here"
```

Another (untested, not near my Ruby):

```
def send_notification(subject, body)
  Mail.deliver do
    from Config.mail['user_name']
    to Config.mail['recipients']
    yield
  end
end

send_notification do
  subject "foo"
  body "your foo is here"
end
```